# What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

Eclipse issues warnings when a `serialVersionUID` is missing.

> The serializable class Foo does not declare a static final
>   serialVersionUID field of type long

What is `serialVersionUID` and why is it important?  Please show an example where missing `serialVersionUID` will cause a problem.

Comment: Find a good practise about serialversionUID; https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-serialversionuid

Comment: Another articles. [mkyong.com/java-best-practices/understand-the-serialversionuid/](https://mkyong.com/java-best-practices/understand-the-serialversionuid/) , [https://www.baeldung.com/java-serial-version-uid](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serial-version-uid)

Comment: If a serialVersionUID is not used when using serialization and deserialization, any change to the class might make the previous seralized version to be unreadable or to have unexpected behavior when deserialized.

Comment: I created a junit test that finds all Serializable classes in my code, fails if any has missing serialVersionUID, and generates a test and some code to insert for adding serialVersionUID at the old value. Might be useful for others. No more forgetting serialVersionUID without a linter or junit failing! https://gist.github.com/arberg/d867185288b0f36aa908f45d6225c40c

Comment: Before you override this value, especially with an automatic too, please read why the lombok-team recommends against it https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

Answer (score 2577, accepted):

The docs for [`java.io.Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html) are probably about as good an explanation as you'll get:

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a version number, called a `serialVersionUID`, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the object that has a different `serialVersionUID` than that of the corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
> [`InvalidClassException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InvalidClassException.html). A serializable class can declare its own `serialVersionUID` explicitly by declaring a field named `serialVersionUID` that must be static, final, and of type `long`:

> ```
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
> ```

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a `serialVersionUID`, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default `serialVersionUID` value for that class based on various aspects of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification. However, it is *strongly recommended* that all serializable classes explicitly declare `serialVersionUID` values, since the default `serialVersionUID` computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected `InvalidClassExceptions` during deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent `serialVersionUID` value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable class must declare an explicit `serialVersionUID` value. It is also strongly advised that explicit `serialVersionUID` declarations use the private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to the immediately declaring class — `serialVersionUID` fields are not useful as inherited members.

Comment: So, what you are saying essentially is that if a user did not understand all the above material, said user aught not bother worrying about serialization? I believe you answered the "how?" rather than explaining the "why?". I, for one, do not understand why I aught bother with SerializableVersionUID.

Comment: The why is in the second paragraph: if you don't explicitly specify serialVersionUID, a value is generated automatically - but that's brittle because it's compiler implementation dependent.

Comment: And why does Eclipse say I need "private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;" when I extend the Exception class?

Comment: @JohnMerlino: Well I wouldn't expect it to say you *need* one - but it may be *suggesting* one in order to help you serialize exceptions correctly. If you're not going to serialize them, you really don't need the constant.

Comment: @JohnMerlino, to answer the why part of you question: Exception implements [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and eclipse warns that you have not set an serialVersionUID, which would be a good idea (if you wan't to serialize the class) to avoid the problems that JonSkeet's post outlines.

Comment: @JonSkeet So does it mean that besides having an identical class definition, I have to use exactly the same version number? How could I know that if I don't have a peek of the source code of the serialized class?

Comment: @smwikipedia: To deserialize data? Yes. It would be odd to deserialize data for a class you didn't have the source to though. Binary serialization shouldn't (IMO) be used as a general purpose public protocol.

Comment: @Ziggy If " .. since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during deserialization." doesn't answer Why then I am afraid, I will have to ask you to define Why :D

Comment: @JonSkeet You have mentioned in your answer "since such declarations apply only to the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not useful as inherited members." could you please explain this? Because as I know if the parent class is serialized the child is also serialized by default, so do we need to declare SerialVersionUID for child as well?

Comment: @JonSkeet If I make it protected then what? Won't it inherited in child class?

Comment: @proudandhonour: I don't know exactly what happens in those cases, but why not just declare it separately in each class, as the documentation implies?

Comment: Just my two cents this is an issue in Spark and other parallelization APIs that depend on serializing Java classes across a cluster.

Comment: @JonSkeet who generates default UID? JVM or Compiler/JDK?

Comment: @UnKnown: The serialization runtime - it's at execution time.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, manually specifying the uid is unsafer than letting the runtime generate it. Because sooner or later someone will forget to update it....

Comment: I can't see any cons against letting the runtime use the class "signature". Seems to be the perfect solution to me.

Comment: @user1050755: So you're happy that changing your compiler, even if it wouldn't change any of the details of the fields themselves, could make any stored data unreadable? Or adding a public static method, which really shouldn't change serialization details? Having been bitten by exactly this sort of thing before, it's a very definite "con". Now it could be that if the algorithm had been designed better, it would be okay - but with the way it *is* designed, it's bad news.

Comment: Tip: If you've forgotten to add the `serialVersionUIDfield`, and you wish to change the class without affecting it, you can check what is its value on the unmodified and set it on this class after you've modified it, using this call (found from : stackoverflow.com/a/26822688/878126): `long serialVersionUID = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(YourClass.class).getSerialVersionUID();`

Comment: So what will happen if I update my class but do not update the `serialVersionUIDfield`?

Comment: @bpoiss: Then it will try to deserialize old data with the new class, and will either cause errors or effectively corrupt data, depending on the exact change.

Comment: I think compilers, linters and other experts cannot decide if I am going to serialize/unserialize my class at all. Or if I do, whether I send it to another application trying to deserialize on a different vendor's JVM than the sending one. So again: Why is it a problem if a class does not define a serialVersionUID?

Comment: @Queeg: if the class is not Serializable, then there will be no warning. If it is Serializable, then the probable problems of not defining a serialVersionUID were explained by Jon Skeet just before your post. Declaring the class as Serializable already states the intent to serialize it, even if it is by subclassing. There's no way for the tools to know that a Serializable class is being used but it won't be serialized, so the safer path is to issue a warning.

Comment: The lombok-team acknowledges this bit of the documentation yet still recommends against overriding the value. https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

Answer (score 522):

If you're serializing just because you have to serialize for the implementation's sake (who cares if you serialize for an `HTTPSession`, for instance...if it's stored or not, you probably don't care about `de-serializing` a form object), then you can ignore this.

If you're actually using serialization, it only matters if you plan on storing and retrieving objects using serialization directly.  The `serialVersionUID` represents your class version, and you should increment it if the current version of your class is not backwards compatible with its previous version.

Most of the time, you will probably not use serialization directly.  If this is the case, generate a default `SerialVersionUID` by clicking the quick fix option and don't worry about it.

Comment: I'd say that if you're not using serialization for permanent storage, you should use @SuppressWarnings rather than adding a value. It clutters the class less, and it preserves the abiity of the serialVersionUID mechanism to protect you from incompatible changes.

Comment: I don't see how adding one line (@SuppressWarnings annotation) as opposed to another line (serializable id) "clutters the class less".  And if you're not using serialization for permanent storage, why wouldn't you just use "1"?  You would not care about the autogenerated ID in that case anyways.

Comment: @MetroidFan2002: I think @TomAnderson's point of `serialVersionUID` protecting you from incompatible changes is valid. Using `@SuppressWarnings` documents the intent better if you don't wish to use the class for permanent storage.

Comment: "You should increment it if the current version of your class is not backwards compatible with its previous version:" You should first explore the extensive object versioning support of Serialization, (a) to ensure that the class really is now serialization-incompatible way, which per the specification is quite difficult to achieve; (b) to try a scheme such as custom read/writeObject() methods, readResolve/writeReplace() methods, serializableFields declarations, etc, to make sure that the stream remains compatible. Changing the actual `serialVersionUID` is a last resort, a counsel of despair.

Comment: @EJP increment of serialVersionUID comes into picture when initial author of the class has introduced explicitly.I would say, jvm generated serial id, should be fine. this is the best [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27601774/3317808) that i saw on serialisation.

Comment: If you're not using serialization (in like 99.9999% of the cases) just turn off this stupid default warning.  No pointless meaningless random numbers in your code and no unnecessary SuppressWarnings.  Jeez, every time I see code bases which "workaround" this warning I really wonder why they not simply turn off this warning (and perhaps activate a few that are more useful), instead of this zombie mentality to just "fix" the warning.

Comment: @TomAnderson No warning are shown in IDEA by default.

Answer (score 367):

I can't pass up this opportunity to plug Josh Bloch's book [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) (2nd Edition).  Chapter 10 is an indispensible resource on Java serialization.

Per Josh, the automatically-generated UID is generated based on a class name, implemented interfaces, and all public and protected members.  Changing any of these in any way will change the `serialVersionUID`.  So you don't need to mess with them only if you are certain that no more than one version of the class will ever be serialized (either across processes or retrieved from storage at a later time).

If you ignore them for now, and find later that you need to change the class in some way but maintain compatibility w/ old version of the class, you can use the JDK tool **serialver** to generate the `serialVersionUID` on the *old* class, and explicitly set that on the new class.  (Depending on your changes you may need to also implement custom serialization by adding `writeObject` and `readObject` methods - see `Serializable` javadoc or aforementioned chapter 10.)

Comment: So one might bother with SerializableVersionUID if one were concerned about compatibility w/ old versions of a class?

Comment: Yup, in case if the newer version changes any public member to protected, the default SerializableVersionUID will be different and will raise an InvalidClassExceptions.

Comment: class Name, implemented interfaces, all public and protected methods,ALL instance variables.

Comment: It is worth noting that Joshua Bloch advices that for *every* Serializable class it's worth specifying the serial version uid. Quote from chapter 11: 

_Regardless of what serialized form you choose, declare an explicit serial version UID in every serializable class you write. This eliminates the serial version UID as a potential source of incompatibility (Item 74). There is also a small performance benefit. If no serial version UID is provided, an expensive computation is required to generate one at runtime._

Comment: Seems relevant. A link to a couple approaches to generate the serial version UID using IDEs: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-generate-serialversionuid/

Answer (score 146):

You can tell Eclipse to ignore these serialVersionUID  warnings:

> Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors / Warnings > Potential Programming Problems

In case you didn't know, there are a lot of other warnings you can enable in this section (or even have some reported as errors), many are very useful:

- Potential Programming Problems: Possible accidental boolean assignment
- Potential Programming Problems: Null pointer access
- Unnecessary code: Local variable is never read
- Unnecessary code: Redundant null check
- Unnecessary code: Unnecessary cast or 'instanceof'

and many more.

Comment: upvote but only because the original poster doesn't appear to be serializing anything.  If the poster said "i'm serializing this thing and ..." then you'd get a vote down instead :P

Comment: @Gardner -> agreed! But the questioner also wants to know why he might not want to be warned.

Comment: The questioner obviously cares about why there should be an UID. So simply telling him to ignore the warn should be downvoted.

Answer (score 126):

`serialVersionUID` facilitates versioning of serialized data. Its value is stored with the data when serializing. When de-serializing, the same version is checked to see how the serialized data matches the current code.

If you want to version your data, you normally start with a `serialVersionUID` of 0, and bump it with every structural change to your class which alters the serialized data (adding or removing non-transient fields).

The built-in de-serialization mechanism (`in.defaultReadObject()`) will refuse to de-serialize from old versions of the data. But if you want to you can define your own [readObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/input.html#2971)-function which can read back old data. This custom code can then check the `serialVersionUID` in order to know which version the data is in and decide how to de-serialize it. This versioning technique is useful if you store serialized data which survives several versions of your code.

But storing serialized data for such a long time span is not very common. It is far more common to use the serialization mechanism to temporarily write data to for instance a cache or send it over the network to another program with the same version of the relevant parts of the codebase.

In this case you are not interested in maintaining backwards compatibility. You are only concerned with making sure that the code bases which are communicating indeed have the same versions of relevant classes. In order to facilitate such a check, you must maintain the `serialVersionUID` just like before and not forget to update it when making changes to your classes.

If you do forget to update the field, you might end up with two different versions of a class with different structure but with the same `serialVersionUID`. If this happens, the default mechanism (`in.defaultReadObject()`) will not detect any difference, and try to de-serialize incompatible data. Now you might end up with a cryptic runtime error or silent failure (null fields). These types of errors might be hard to find.

So to help this usecase, the Java platform offers you a choice of not setting the `serialVersionUID` manually. Instead, a hash of the class structure will be generated at compile-time and used as id. This mechanism will make sure that you never have different class structures with the same id, and so you will not get these hard-to-trace runtime serialization failures mentioned above.

But there is a backside to the auto-generated id strategy. Namely that the generated ids for the same class might differ between compilers (as mentioned by Jon Skeet above). So if you communicate serialized data between code compiled with different compilers, it is recommended to maintain the ids manually anyway.

And if you are backwards-compatible with your data like in the first use case mentioned, you also probably want to maintain the id yourself. This in order to get readable ids and have greater control over when and how they change.

Comment: Adding or removing non-transient fields doesn't make the class serialization-incompatible. There is therefore no reason to 'bump it' on such changes.

Comment: @EJP: Huh? Adding data definitely changes the serialization data in my world.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling Read what I wrote. I didn't say it doesn't 'change the serialization data'. I said it 'doesn't make the class serialization-incompatible'. It isn't the same thing. You need to read the Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification.

Comment: @EJP: I realize that adding a non-transient field  doesn't necessarily mean that you make the class serialization-incompatible, but it is a structural change which alters the serialized data and you usually want to bump the version when doing so unless you handle backwards compatibility, which I also explained later in the post. What is your point exactly?

Comment: My point remains exactly what I said. Adding or removing non-transient fields doesn't make the class Serialization-incompatible.  You therefore don't need to bump the serialVersionUID every time you do so.

Comment: According to this article by the lombok team the version check kicks in _before_ your custom `readObject`: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

Answer (score 81):

> What is a **serialVersionUID** and why should I use it?

`SerialVersionUID` is a unique identifier for each class, `JVM` uses it to compare the versions of the class ensuring that the same class was used during Serialization is loaded during Deserialization.

Specifying one gives more control, though JVM does generate one if you don't specify. The value generated can differ between different compilers. Furthermore, sometimes you just want for some reason to forbid deserialization of old serialized objects [`backward incompatibility`], and in this case you just have to change the serialVersionUID.

**The [javadocs for `Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) say**:

> the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected `InvalidClassException`s during
>   deserialization.

**Therefore, you must declare serialVersionUID because it give us more control**.

[This article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45) has some good points on the topic.

Comment: @Vinothbabu but serialVersionUID is static so static variables cannot be serialized. then how come jvm will check version, without knowing what is the version of the deserializing object

Comment: The one thing not mentioned in this answer is that you may cause unintended consequences by blindly including `serialVersionUID` without knowing why. Tom Anderson's comment on MetroidFan2002's answer addresses this: "I'd say that if you're not using serialization for permanent storage, you should use @SuppressWarnings rather than adding a value. It clutters the class less, and it preserves the ability of the serialVersionUID mechanism to protect you from incompatible changes."

Comment: `serialVersionUID` is *not* a 'unique identifier for each class'. The fully-qualified class name is that. It is a *version* indicator.

Comment: can a serialVersionUID same for different classes?

Comment: thanks @Kirby - I don't know why I never used SuppressWarnings for serialVersionUID in decades, just sometimes obediently following the warning and sometimes ignoring it. Maybe because of "we may need it when we start clustering services and applications". Maybe an IDE should change it if needed (for example based on changes against a VCS).

Answer (score 65):

Original question has asked for 'why is it important' and 'example' where this `Serial Version ID` would be useful. Well I have found one.

Say you create a `Car` class, instantiate it, and write it out to an object stream. The flattened car object sits in the file system for some time. Meanwhile, if the `Car` class is modified by adding a new field. Later on, when you try to read (i.e. deserialize) the flattened `Car` object, you get the `java.io.InvalidClassException` – because all serializable classes are automatically given a unique identifier. This exception is thrown when the identifier of the class is not equal to the identifier of the flattened object. If you really think about it, the exception is thrown because of the addition of the new field. You can avoid this exception being thrown by controlling the versioning yourself by declaring an explicit serialVersionUID. There is also a small performance benefit in explicitly declaring your `serialVersionUID` (because does not have to be calculated). So, it is best practice to add your own serialVersionUID to your Serializable classes as soon as you create them as shown below:

```
public class Car {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; //assign a long value
}
```

Comment: And one should assign a random long number, not 1L, to every UID.

Comment: @abbas 'One should' do that why? Please explain what difference it makes.

Comment: As the name says, it represents the version of the class that was used to serialize the object. If you assign it the same number every time, you won't be able to find the right class to de-serialize it. So whenever you make a change in the class, it is better to change the version too.

Comment: @abbas, this intention doesn't clash with using incrementing natural numbers from `1` and so on.

Comment: @BillK, I thought serialization check is bound to the pair of classname and serialVersionUID. So different numbering schemes of different classes and libraries can't interfere in any way. Or did you imply code-generating libraries?

Comment: @abbas `serialVersionUID` doesn't have anything to do with 'find[ing] the right version of the class'.

Comment: The thing I always found crazy was that the algorithm to derive serialVersionUID when none is explicitly declared is based on package, name, attributes but ALSO methods... methods are not serialized and adding/removing methods makes no difference to the serialized form of the object so why produce a different serialVersionUID when a method is added/deleted/changed"?

Comment: I am getting InvalidClassException because i haven't define serialVersionUID on the first place, how to fix this issue now ?

Comment: @MugeeshHusain No you aren't. Omitting it doesn't cause that exception. Changing the class subsequently does. All you need to do *now* is to add a `serialVersionUID` member whose value is whatever the exception said the 'stream value' was.

Answer (score 62):

First I need to explain what serialization is.

**Serialization** allows to convert an object to a stream, for sending that object over the network OR Save to file OR save into DB for later usage.

***There are some rules for serialization***.

- An object is serializable only if its class or its superclass implements the Serializable interface
- An object is serializable (itself implements the Serializable interface) even if its superclass is not. However, the first superclass in the hierarchy of the serializable class, that does not implements Serializable interface, MUST have a no-arg constructor. If this is violated, readObject() will produce a java.io.InvalidClassException in runtime
- All primitive types are serializable.
- Transient fields (with transient modifier) are NOT serialized, (i.e., not saved or restored). A class that implements Serializable must mark transient fields of classes that do not support serialization (e.g., a file stream).
- Static fields (with static modifier) are not serialized.

When `Object` is serialized, Java Runtime associates the serial version number aka, the `serialVersionID`.

***Where we need serialVersionID:***

During the deserialization to verify that sender and receiver are compatible with respect to serialization. If the receiver loaded the class with a different `serialVersionID` then deserialization will end with `InvalidClassCastException`.
A serializable class can declare its own `serialVersionUID` explicitly by declaring a field named `serialVersionUID` that must be static, final, and of type long.

Let's try this with an example.

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String empname;
    private byte empage;

    public String getEmpName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }

    public byte getEmpAge() {
        return empage;
    }

    public void setEmpAge(byte empage) {
        this.empage = empage;
    }

    public String whoIsThis() {
        return getEmpName() + " is " + getEmpAge() + "years old";
    }
}
```

Create Serialize Object

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Writer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpName("Jagdish");
        employee.setEmpAge((byte) 30);

        FileOutputStream fout = new
                FileOutputStream("/users/Jagdish.vala/employee.obj");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(employee);
        oos.close();
        System.out.println("Process complete");
    }
}
```

Deserialize the object

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/users/Jagdish.vala/employee.obj");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        employee = (Employee) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        System.out.println(employee.whoIsThis());
    }
}
```

NOTE: Now change the serialVersionUID of the Employee class and save:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
```

And execute the Reader class. Not to execute the Writer class and you will get the exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: 
com.jagdish.vala.java.serialVersion.Employee; local class incompatible: 
stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 4
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at com.krishantha.sample.java.serialVersion.Reader.main(Reader.java:14)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - the local class is the one that you are currently having/using in the classpath and the stream one is the one used by another party (eg. a server that is returning you an answer and has serialized the response). You can encounter this situation when you are communicating with a server that has updated its 3rd party libs, but you (the client) did not yer done this.

Answer (score 43):

If you will never need to serialize your objects to byte array and send/store them, then you don't need to worry about it. If you do, then you must consider your serialVersionUID since the deserializer of the object will match it to the version of object its classloader has. Read more about it in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: If you're not going to serialize the objects, why are they Serializable?

Comment: @erickson - the parent class may be serializable, say, ArrayList, but you want your own object (say, a modified array list) to use it as a base but are never going to serialize the Collection that you create.

Comment: It isn't mentioned anywhere in the Java Language Specification. It's mentioned in the Object Versioning Specification.

Comment: Here is the link to the Java 8 [Object Versioning Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).

Answer (score 37):

If you get this warning on a class you don't ever think about serializing, and that you didn't declare yourself `implements Serializable`, it is often because you inherited from a superclass, which implements Serializable. Often then it would be better to delegate to such a object instead of using inheritance.

So, instead of

```
public class MyExample extends ArrayList<String> {

    public MyExample() {
        super();
    }
    ...
}
```

do

```
public class MyExample {
    private List<String> myList;

    public MyExample() {
         this.myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    ...
}
```

and in the relevant methods call `myList.foo()` instead of `this.foo()` (or `super.foo()`). (This does not fit in all cases, but still quite often.)

I often see people extending JFrame or such, when they really only need to delegate to this. (This also helps for auto-completing in a IDE, since JFrame has hundreds of methods, which you don't need when you want to call your custom ones on your class.)

One case where the warning (or the serialVersionUID) is unavoidable is when you extend from AbstractAction, normally in a anonymous class, only adding the actionPerformed-method. I think there shouldn't be a warning in this case (since you normally can't reliable serialize and deserialize such anonymous classes anyway accross different versions of your class), but I'm not sure how the compiler could recognize this.

Comment: I think you're right that composition over inhneritance makes more sense, particularly when you're discussing classes such as ArrayList. However, many frameworks require people to extend from abstract superclasses which are serializable (such as Struts 1.2's ActionForm class, or Saxon's ExtensionFunctionDefinition) in which case this solution is infeasible.

I think you're right, it would be nice if the warning were ignored in certain cases (like if you were extending from an abstract serializable class)

Comment: Surely if you add a class as a member, rather than inheriting from it, you would have to write a wrapper method for EVERY method of the member class that you wished to use, which would make it unfeasible in a large number of situations... unless java has a function similar to perl's `__AUTOLOAD`, which I don't know about.

Comment: @M_M: When you would delegate lots of methods to your wrapped object, of course it would not be appropriate to use delegation. But I suppose that this case is a sign of a design mistake - the users of your class (e.g. "MainGui") shouldn't need to call lots of methods of the wrapped object (e.g. JFrame).

Comment: What I don't like about delegation is the need to hold a reference to the delegate. And every reference means more memory. Correct me if I'm wrong. If I need a  CustomizedArrayList of 100 objects then this wouldn't matter much but if I need hundreds of CustomizdeArrayLists of a few objects then memory usage increases significantly.

Comment: Throwable is serializable, and only Throwable is throwable, so it's not possible to define an exception that isn't serializable.  Delegation isn't possible.

Comment: @Phil I think this is by design – even if you don't want to serialize your exception class, someone else might want to serialize an exception thrown by you. (Of course, one could argue that most exception classes should be fine with the auto-generated serialVersionUID and not need a fixed one.)

Answer (score 23):

To understand the significance of field serialVersionUID, one should understand how Serialization/Deserialization works.

When a Serializable class object is serialized Java Runtime associates a serial version no.(called as serialVersionUID) with this serialized object. At the time when you deserialize this serialized object Java Runtime matches the serialVersionUID of serialized object with the serialVersionUID of the class. If both are equal then only it proceeds with the further process of deserialization else throws InvalidClassException.

So we conclude that to make Serialization/Deserialization process successful the serialVersionUID of serialized object must be equivalent to the serialVersionUID of the class. In case if programmer specifies the serialVersionUID value explicitly in the program then the same value will be associated with the serialized object and the class, irrespective of the serialization and deserialzation platform(for ex. serialization might be done on platform like windows by using sun or MS JVM and Deserialization might be on different platform Linux using Zing JVM).

But in case if serialVersionUID is not specified by programmer then while doing Serialization\DeSerialization  of any object, Java runtime uses its own algorithm to calculate it. This serialVersionUID calculation algorithm varies from one JRE to another. It is also possible that the environment where the object is serialized is using one JRE (ex: SUN JVM) and the environment where deserialzation happens is using Linux Jvm(zing). In such cases serialVersionUID associated with serialized object will be different than the serialVersionUID of class calculated at deserialzation environment. In turn deserialization will not be successful. So to avoid such situations/issues programmer must always specify serialVersionUID of Serializable class.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't vary, but it is slightly under-specified.

Comment: ... the algorithm doesn't vary, but it is slightly under-specified... meaning any jvm may vary..... @user207421

Answer (score 20):

As for an example where the missing serialVersionUID might cause a problem:

I'm working on this Java EE application that is composed of a Web module that uses an `EJB` module. The web module calls the `EJB` module remotely and passes a `POJO` that implements `Serializable` as an argument.

This `POJO's` class was packaged inside the EJB jar and inside it's own jar in the WEB-INF/lib of the web module. They're actually the same class, but when I package the EJB module I unpack this POJO's jar to pack it together with the EJB module.

The call to the `EJB` was failing with the Exception below because I hadn't declared its `serialVersionUID`:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mismatched serialization UIDs : Source
 (Rep.
 IDRMI:com.hordine.pedra.softbudget.domain.Budget:5CF7CE11E6810A36:04A3FEBED5DA4588)
 = 04A3FEBED5DA4588 whereas Target (Rep. ID RMI:com.hordine.pedra.softbudget.domain.Budget:7AF5ED7A7CFDFF31:6227F23FA74A9A52)
 = 6227F23FA74A9A52
```

Answer (score 18):

Don't bother, the default calculation is really good and suffice for 99,9999% of the cases. And if you run into problems, you can - as already stated - introduce UID's as the need arrise (which is highly unlikely)

Comment: Rubbish. It is adequate in the case where the class hasn't changed. You have zero evidence to support '99.9999%'.

Comment: The problem is not that it isn't "good", but it isn't guaranteed to be consistent over different versions.

Comment: You will always run into problems without serialVersionUID if you have to change a class that has to stay backward compatible with it's serialization.

Answer (score 18):

I generally use `serialVersionUID` in one context:  When I know it will be leaving the context of the Java VM.

I would know this when I to use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for my application or if I know a library/framework I use will use it.  The serialVersionID ensures different Java VMs of varying versions or vendors will inter-operate correctly or if it is stored and retrieved outside the VM for example `HttpSession` the session data can remain even during a restart and upgrade of the application server.

For all other cases, I use

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
```

since most of the time the default `serialVersionUID` is sufficient.  This includes `Exception`, `HttpServlet`.

Comment: It doesn't include HttpServlet in containers where they can be swapped out, or Exception in RMI for example.

Answer (score 15):

Field data represents some information stored in the class.
Class implements the `Serializable` interface, 
so eclipse automatically offered  to declare the `serialVersionUID` field. Lets start with value 1 set there.

If you don't want that warning to come, use this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
```

Comment: sane answer to a not-so-sane warning. The lombok-team recommends not overriding the field so I think this warning is safe to supress: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

Answer (score 13):

**Why use `SerialVersionUID` inside `Serializable` class in Java?**

During `serialization`, Java runtime creates a version number for a class, so that it can de-serialize it later. This version number is known as `SerialVersionUID` in Java.

`SerialVersionUID` is used to version serialized data. You can only de-serialize a class if it's `SerialVersionUID` matches with the serialized instance. When we don't declare `SerialVersionUID` in our class, Java runtime generates it for us but its not recommended. It's recommended to declare `SerialVersionUID` as `private static final long` variable to avoid default mechanism.

When you declare a class as `Serializable` by implementing marker interface `java.io.Serializable`, Java runtime persist instance of that class into disk by using default Serialization mechanism, provided you have not customized the process using `Externalizable` interface.

see also [Why use SerialVersionUID inside Serializable class in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/05/why-use-serialversionuid-inside-serializable-class-in-java.html)

Comment: The lombok-team actually recommends letting the Java-runtime generate it, precisely for the purpose of failing deserialization when the class changed: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

Answer (score 12):

SerialVersionUID is used for version control of object. you can specify serialVersionUID in your class file also. Consequence of not specifying serialVersionUID is that when you add or modify any field in class then already serialized class will not be able to recover because serialVersionUID generated for new class and for old serialized object will be different. Java serialization process relies on correct serialVersionUID for recovering state of serialized object and throws java.io.InvalidClassException in case of serialVersionUID mismatch

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/top-10-java-serialization-interview.html#ixzz3VQxnpOPZ

Comment: No, if you add or remove a field, you have made a binary-incompatible change to your class and the deserialization _should_ fail, because if it does not fail, it likely produces nonsensical data. Please read this article from the lombok-team: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

Answer (score 11):

It would be nice if CheckStyle could verify that the serialVersionUID on a class that implements Serializable has a good value, i.e. that it matches what the serial version id  generator would produce.  If you have a project with lots of serializable DTOs, for example, remembering to delete the existing serialVersionUID and regenerate it is a pain, and currently the only way (that I know of) to verify this is to regenerate for each class and compare to the old one.  This is very very painful.

Comment: If you set the serialVersionUID always to the same value the generator would produce, you don't really need it at all. After all, its raison d'être is to stay same after changes, when the class is still compatible.

Comment: The reason is so that different compilers come up with the same value for the same class.  As explained in the javadocs (also answered above), the generated version is brittle and can vary even when the class is properly deserializable.  As long as you run this test on the same compiler each time, it should be safe.  god help you if you upgrade the jdk and a new rule comes out, even though you code didn't change.

Comment: It's not required to match what `serialver` would produce. -1

Comment: In general it's not required at all.  @AndrewBacker's case would require two different compilers on the same .java file with both versions of the .class files communicating with each other--most of the time you just create the class and distribute it.  If that's the case, then not having an SUID would work fine.

Comment: People that truly use Serialization for purposes of storage / retrieval will generally set the `serialVersionUID` to 1.  If a newer version of the class is incompatible, but still requires to be able to handle the old data, you increment the version number and add special code to deal with older formats.  I cry every time I see a `serialVersionUID` larger than 1 digit, either because it was a random number (useless) or because the class apparently needs to deal with more than 10 different versions.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to amend a huge number of classes which had no serialVersionUID set in the first place while maintain the compatibility with the old classes, tools like IntelliJ Idea, Eclipse fall short as they generate random numbers and does not work on a bunch of files in one go. I come up the following bash script(I'm sorry for Windows users, consider buy a Mac or convert to Linux) to make amending serialVersionUID issue with ease:

```sh
base_dir=$(pwd)                                                                  
src_dir=$base_dir/src/main/java                                                  
ic_api_cp=$base_dir/target/classes                                               

while read f                                                                     
do                                                                               
    clazz=${f//\//.}                                                             
    clazz=${clazz/%.java/}                                                       
    seruidstr=$(serialver -classpath $ic_api_cp $clazz | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed -e 's/^\s\+//')
    perl -ni.bak -e "print $_; printf qq{%s\n}, q{    private $seruidstr} if /public class/" $src_dir/$f
done
```

you save the this script, say add_serialVersionUID.sh to you ~/bin. Then you run it in the root directory of your Maven or Gradle project like:

```
add_serialVersionUID.sh < myJavaToAmend.lst
```

This .lst includes the list of java files to add the serialVersionUID in the following format:

```
com/abc/ic/api/model/domain/item/BizOrderTransDO.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/domain/item/CardPassFeature.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/domain/item/CategoryFeature.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/domain/item/GoodsFeature.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/domain/item/ItemFeature.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/domain/item/ItemPicUrls.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/domain/item/ItemSkuDO.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/domain/serve/ServeCategoryFeature.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/domain/serve/ServeFeature.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/param/depot/DepotItemDTO.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/param/depot/DepotItemQueryDTO.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/param/depot/InDepotDTO.java
com/abc/ic/api/model/param/depot/OutDepotDTO.java
```

This script uses the JDK serialVer tool under hood. So make sure your $JAVA_HOME/bin is in the PATH.

Comment: Gives me an idea: always regenerate the serial version uid with a tool like this, never by hand, before making a release - that way, you avoid forgetting to make a change to a class whose serial version uid should have changed because of an actual incompatible change. Keeping track of that manually is very hard.

Comment: This is somewhere between useless and harmful. Please read the article from the lombok-team on why serialVersionUID should not be auto-generated: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

Comment: When I came up this little tool, there is no such lombok document. ;-(

Contrary to the assumption of the lombok, I believe in most serious Java development organizations, ensuring the back-compatibility of a class is the norm. So use of serialVersionUID is to be consistent to with Java serialization mechanism. My tool may offer little assistance in this regard.  If you use more advanced serialization mechanisms such as protobuf, thrift, dubbo, then it is not useful.

Answer (score 7):

This question is very well documented in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch. A very good book and a must read. I will outline some of the reasons below :

The serialization runtime comes up with a number called Serial version for each serializable class. This number is called serialVersionUID. Now there is some Math behind this number and it comes out based on the fields/methods that are defined in the class. For the same class the same version is generated every time. This number is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an InvalidClassException.

If the class is serializable you can also declare your own serialVersionUID explicitly  by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long. Most IDE's like Eclipse help you generate that long string.

Comment: This is a good explanation of the mechanism but generating this field with an IDE is either useless or harmful, according to this excellent article by the lombok-team: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

Answer (score 6):

Each time an object is serialized the object is stamped with a version ID number for the object's class.This ID is called [serialVersionUID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285793/1387612) and it is computed based on information about the class structure. Suppose you made an Employee class and it has version id #333 (assigned by JVM),Now when you will serialize the object of that class (Suppose Employee object), JVM will assign UID to it as #333.

Consider a situation - in the future you need to edit or change your class and in that case when you modify it, JVM will assign it a new UID (Suppose #444).
Now when you try to deserialize the employee object, JVM will compare serialized object's (Employee object) version ID(#333) with that of the class i.e #444(Since it was changed). On comparison JVM will find both version UID are different and hence Deserialization will fail.
Hence if serialVersionID for each class is defined by programmer itself. It will be same even if the class is evolved in future and hence JVM will always find that class is compatible with serialized object even though the class is changed. For more Info you can refer chapter 14 of HEAD FIRST JAVA.

Comment: Each time the *class* of an object is serialized the `serialVersionUID` is transmitted. It isn't sent with every object.

Comment: @user207421 It is saved on every object, according to: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID If it wasn't, the mechanism of failing the deserialization could not possibly work.

Answer (score 4):

A Simple Explanation:

1. Are you serializing data?

   Serialization is basically writing class data to a file/stream/etc.  De-serialization is reading that data back to a class.
2. Do you intend to go into production?

   If you are just testing something with unimportant/fake data, then don't worry about it (unless you are testing serialization directly).
3. Is this the first version?

   If so, set `serialVersionUID=1L`.
4. Is this the second, third, etc. prod version?

   Now you need to worry about `serialVersionUID`, and should look into it in depth.

Basically, if you don't update the version correctly when you update a class you need to write/read, you will get an error when you try to read old data.

Answer (score 3):

To tell the long story short this field is used to check if serialized data can be deserialized correctly. Serialization and deserialization are often made by different copies of program - for example server converts object to string and client converts received string to object. This field tells that both operates with same idea about what this object is. This field helps when:

- you have many different copies of your program in different places (like 1 server and 100 clients). If you will change your object, alter your version number and forget to update one this clients, it will know that he is not capable of deserialization
- you have stored your data in some file and later on you try to open it with updated version of your program with modified object - you will know that this file is not compatible if you keep your version right

When is it important?

Most obvious - if you add some fields to your object, older versions will not be able to use them because they do not have these fields in their object structure.

Less obvious - When you deserialize object, fields that where not present in string will be kept as NULL. If you have removed field from your object, older versions will keep this field as allways-NULL that can lead to misbehavior if older versions rely on data in this field (anyway you have created it for something, not just for fun :-) )

Least obvious - Sometimes you change the idea you put in some field's meaning. For example when you are 12 years old you mean "bicycle" under "bike", but when you are 18 you mean "motorcycle" - if your friends will invite you to "bike ride across city" and you will be the only one who came on bicycle, you will undestand how important it is to keep same meaning across fields :-)

Answer (score 3):

'serialVersionUID' is a 64 bit number used to uniquely identify a class during deserialization process. When you serialize an object, serialVersionUID of the class also written to the file. Whenever you deserialize this object, java run time extract this serialVersionUID value from the serialized data and compare the same value associate with the class. If both do not match, then 'java.io.InvalidClassException' will be thrown.

If a serializable class do not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then serialization runtime will calculate  serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class like fields, methods etc.,, You can refer this [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2014/09/serialversionuid.html) for demo application.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly to answer your question, when we don't declare SerialVersionUID in our class, Java runtime generates it for us, but that process is sensitive to many class meta data including number of fields, type of fields, access modifier of fields, interface implemented by class etc. Therefore it is recommended to declare it ourselves and Eclipse is warning you about the same.

Serialization:
We often work with important objects whose state (data in the variables of the object) is so important that we can not risk to lose it due to power/system failures (or) network failures in case of sending the object state to other machine. The solution for this problem is named "Persistence" which simply means persisting (holding/saving) the data. Serialization is one of many other ways to achieve persistence (by saving data to disk/memory). When saving the state of the object, it is important to create an identity for the object, to be able to properly read it back (de-serialization). This unique identification is ID is SerialVersionUID.

Comment: The first paragraph is true but misleading, when the class-metadata you mention changes, you cannot deserialize your old data just like that. Overriding serialVersionUID will just deactivate the JVMs sanity-check and is a bad way to go. Please read https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** manually define serialVersionUID, at least not without careful consideration.

Many tutorials, developers and linting-tools have wrong ideas about this field. This excellent article from the lombok-team exists to explain why serialVersionUID cannot be generated by a tool and in that process also explains what many developers get wrong about this concept, I strongly recommend reading the whole thing before trying any of the 'solutions' to this question.

https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID

They explain what the serialVersionUID-mechanism does in Java:

- All classes have a serialVersionUID, whether you define it or not.
- Any serialized object stores the serialVersionUID in addition to its classname and data
- Deserialization fails if the serialVersionUID of the serialized object does not match the serialVersionUID of that same class in the currently executing JVM
- The default serialVersionUID changes every time your class changes.

**The default-behaviour you get from not defining serialVersionUID is actually what you want.** If a serializable class changes, the system prevents you from deserializing old data into it, as it would potentially produce rubbish.

Only if you *want* to deserialize old data into a modified class it becomes necessary to tell Java this is OK by defining a serialVersionUID on your class *and make sure that you actually can read old data*. You can achieve this by never doing a change that hurts binary compatibility or by using writeReplace/readResolve, or writeObject/readObject.
This is hard, and the responsibility for getting this correct is on the programmer. You should really think about whether that is necessary.